# Tailwind CSS: Configure for a default color hue

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure tailwind to have a default hue to be used when there is not a number appended to the end. For example, if you could just have `bg-blue` instead of `bg-blue-x00`? This would be particularly useful when implementing a color palate where you are going to use the same exact color often, but don't want to name them `primary` or `main` or something like that.

Intuitively, I'd think it would look something like this if such a feature exists?

```js
blue: {
  default: "rgb(23 124 204)",  // this would be "bg-blue" or "text-blue"
  100: "rgb(177 221 255)",
  200: "rgb(123 189 240)",
  300: "rgb(86 181 254)",
  400: "rgb(0 144 255)",
  500: "rgb(23 124 204)",
  600: "rgb(33 114 178)",
  700: "#3f7cac",
  800: "rgb(0 74 133)",
  900: "rgb(0 60 109)",
}
```

Is this a thing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is, but `default` key should be uppercase like `DEFAULT`. This way you may use default color like `bg-blue`

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blue: {
          DEFAULT: "rgb(23 124 204)",  // this would be "bg-blue" or "text-blue"
          100: "rgb(177 221 255)",
          200: "rgb(123 189 240)",
          300: "rgb(86 181 254)",
          400: "rgb(0 144 255)",
          500: "rgb(23 124 204)",
          600: "rgb(33 114 178)",
          700: "#3f7cac",
          800: "rgb(0 74 133)",
          900: "rgb(0 60 109)",
        },
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also this applied to `@apply` [directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply)

```
.apply {
  @apply bg-blue;
}
```

but it will **NOT** work with `theme()` [function](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) - you need define full path to default key

```
.theme {
  background-color: theme('colors.blue.DEFAULT');
  /** background-color: theme('colors.blue'); will not work */
}
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/B4r9SFA7fC)

Comment: Any idea why this is not implemented in out of the box? Seems like 'bg-red', or 'text-indigo' would be a useful, succinct choice.

Comment: I know you can create a DEFAULT for within an entire custom color range, but "bg-blue", "text-red", etc. do NOT render out of the box. Seems common sense to me that "bg-blue" would render "blue" (the center most color of a value range from light to dark). I appreciate your response.

Comment: @WillC Oh you're right it does not render out of the box. I somehow thought they are... However I'm never using Tailwind color palette and create my own color keys in every project

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I add my custom colors formatted like 'bg_color_aqua' and usually don't use the built in color ranges except to debug/quick layout which is why bg_red, bg_blue would be useful. I'll chime in on the repo if it is worth it.